# Average number of observations required to decode a scrambled lock?

Tags: combinatorics

(Based off of a youtube video recently posted by LockPickingLawyer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMLyDx_ZAXs)

Given 4 cells, each containing 3 random digits from 0-9 (with repeats) and a 6 digit pin -- on average how many times would someone need to watch the pin being entered before they could succesfully decode the correct pin? (The cells only change values after the code is entered correctly or incorrectly.)

Is there a general equation for n cells, containg i digits, and k length pins? (Ignoring the trivial case of if a cell contains all digits 0-9).

Comment: Is this all you've got for us today?

Comment: if we had a 1 digit pin (let's say it is 1), then the first press narrows it down to 3 digits.  Assuming the digits are random then there is a 7/9 * 6 / 8 = .58 chance that the two wrong digits are not the same as before, so then you've got the pin.  And there is I think 20% chance you get just 1 repeat, narrowing it down to 1 number, but just 3% chance of same 3 numbers.  So you can see already that for a 1 digit pin, it will not take long.  the 6 digit pin is solving in parallel , so that won't take long either.  No I can't work out a general formula - no idea sorry

Comment: the best bet seems a recurrence relation, you've got this problem that 1,2,3 can appear, but then so can 1,8,9 - but I guess you can say he selects the one he wants randomly